# Is there a queue in threads

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example,If at the moment when the thread processing has not yet ended, but the class has already twitched a second time, will a queue be created and the second class will be processed after the completion of the first one or will it disappear?

```
class main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self): 
        
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(50)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = main()
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no queue here. You have two threads and the main thread will wait on the `t1` thread until it finishes (due to the call `t1.join()`).

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by _"twitched a second time"._ What is twitched and what does it mean it does it a second time?

Comment: the first time the class is called, and after 5 seconds the class is called the second time

Comment: Probably because you start it twice, once in the initializer and once explicitly.

Comment: What are you even talking about? "but the class has already twitched a second time"? I have no idea what you think it means for a class to "twitch", or why a class might "twitch" twice in this code.

Comment: "the first time the class is called, and after 5 seconds the class is called the second time" - you're not doing anything after 5 seconds.